# How to get hours and minutes by subtracting two dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the hours and minutes between two dates. But it's not working and I getting this error

```
    ORA-01843: not a valid month
    01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
```

Here's the script

```
     select q.name as queue_name
        ,to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        ,to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(t.close_time - t.create_time, 'DAY')*24
        ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(t.close_time - t.create_time, 'DAY')*24*60
  from app_account.otrs_ticket t
  left join app_account.otrs_user u
  on t.create_user_id=u.id
  left join app_account.otrs_queue q
  on q.id=t.queue_id
  group by to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
          ,to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
          ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(t.close_time - t.create_time, 'DAY')*24
        ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(t.close_time - t.create_time, 'DAY')*24*60
        ,q.name
  order by to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') desc;
```

Comment: What is the data type of columns `create_time` and `close_time`? In case of `DATE`, why do you cast a `DATE` with `TO_DATE(...)`?

Comment: the data type is date. how?

Comment: Why do you convert a `DATE` into a `DATE`???

Comment: No. I just want to get the difference of two dates (create - close time) with hours and minutes result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you will get atleast idea how to calculate time difference between two dates.

```
   SELECT floor(((date1-date2)*24*60*60)/3600)
            || ' HOURS ' ||
             floor((((date1-date2)*24*60*60) -
           floor(((date1-date2)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)
            || ' MINUTES ' ||
            round((((date1-date2)*24*60*60) -
             floor(((date1-date2)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600 -
            (floor((((date1-date2)*24*60*60) -
           floor(((date1-date2)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)*60) ))
          || ' SECS ' time_difference
     FROM dates;

    TIME_DIFFERENCE
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    24 HOURS 0 MINUTES 0 SECS
    1 HOURS 0 MINUTES 0 SECS
    0 HOURS 1 MINUTES 0 SECS
```

For Futher Reference Please Refer This Link : 
[Click Here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_get_the_time_difference_between_two_date_columns)

Comment: @have this error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Answer (score 1):

use `NUMTODSINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY') or NUMTOYMINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY')` for calculating the difference in days.

For hours multiply the value with 24 and for minutes with 24*60.

```
select q.name as queue_name
            ,to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as create_date
            ,to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as close_date
            ,NUMTODSINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY') or NUMTOYMINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY')*24
            ,NUMTODSINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY') or NUMTOYMINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY') *24*60
      from app_account.otrs_ticket t
      left join app_account.otrs_user u
      on t.create_user_id=u.id
      left join app_account.otrs_queue q
      on q.id=t.queue_id
      where q.name not like 'Facilities Management::%'
      and q.name not like 'HR::%'
      and q.name not like 'Raw%'
      and q.name not like 'Procurement::%'
      and q.name not like 'Facilities Management%'
      and q.name not like 'Junk%'
      and q.name not like 'Facility Request Test%'
      and q.name not like 'Misc%'
      and q.name not like 'POS::POS issue - need paper%'
      group by to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as create_date
              ,to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as close_date
      order by to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') desc;
```

Comment: I use NUMTOYMINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY') *24*60 and NUMTOYMINTERVAL(close_date - create_date, 'DAY')*24 and there's an error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @User014019 You can not select  values that are not in the `group by` clause. So you have to add all values in the `select` to `group by`

Comment: yes i know, pls see the updated query. that query still not working and getting still this error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: @User014019 the q.name column is also missing in group by.

Comment: ok, i put q.name in group by and then i get a new error with NUMTOYMINTERVAL. pls see updated query

Comment: Maybe you hav eto convert the columns to date so replace `t.close_time` with `to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
` and same with `t.create_time`

Comment: I have this ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(to_date(t.close_time, - t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) *24
            ,NUMTOYMINTERVAL(to_date(t.close_time, - t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))*24*60 but this error exist ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"

Comment: @User that is wrong. Change to `NUMTOYMINTERVAL(to_date(t.close_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(t.create_time, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) *24`

Comment: still i got this ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to calculate the values directly without using any oracle function:

Here is an example:

```
WITH q AS
(SELECT TO_DATE(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS d_start,
        TO_DATE(close_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')        AS d_end
   FROM app_account.otrs_ticket
)
SELECT FLOOR((d_end - d_start) * 24)                                                   AS hours,
       FLOOR(((d_end     - d_start) * 24 * 60) - (floor((d_end - d_start) * 24) * 60)) AS minutes
  FROM q;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have this ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: Without the query where this error occures, I can't help!

Comment: here WITH tablename AS (
    SELECT TO_DATE(create_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS d_start,
           TO_DATE(close_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AS d_end
      from tablename
)
SELECT FLOOR((d_end - d_start) * 24) AS hours,
       FLOOR(((d_end - d_start) * 24 * 60) - (floor((d_end - d_start) * 24) * 60)) AS minutes
  from tablename

Comment: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Answer (score 0):

Cast your DATE (or whatever data type it is) to a `TIMESTAMP`. The difference gives you an `INTERVAL` value where you can extract all information. Should be like this:

```
EXTRACT(DAY FROM CAST(t.close_time AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(t.create_time AS TIMESTAMP))*24*60
+ EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(t.close_time AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(t.create_time AS TIMESTAMP))*60
+ EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CAST(t.close_time AS TIMESTAMP) - CAST(t.create_time AS TIMESTAMP)) AS MINUTES
```